# How to query JSON data from an object in sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm new in sequelize so I'd like to ask how to query some specific data from JSON, the JSON in question is inside an onject. Suppose I have this data structure:

```
{ id: INTEGER, name: json, email: STRING}
{ id: 1, name : { "first": "foo", "last": "bar"}, email: blabla@gmail.com}
```

And want to retrieve only id and only "last" from all data like this:

```
{{id: 1, name: {"last": "baz"}, {id: 2, name: {"last": "doe"}}
```

How can I do this with sequelize guys? I'm really lost. I use postgres as database by the way. Thanks.

Comment: It seems you need to use PostgreSQL JSON functions using `Sequelize.fn` in `attributes` option

Comment: Thanks for your response, can you explain more please?

Comment: I can show an approach in the answer but I don't know exact functions you will need to use to reconstruct JSON-object with only one field, you need to look at all JSON-functions that your version of PostgreSQL supports.,

Comment: I already search on the doc but I can't figure out the solution, the doc on JSONB is pretty limited. But I you have some link on your approach, It would be nice

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL do you use?

Comment: I'm using the version 6

Comment: THAT old? Are you sure?

Comment: Ooh sorry, it's 12.9, and v6 for sequelize

Comment: I hope this `select json_build_object('b', '{"b":"test", "d": "test2"}'::json#>'{b}')` will help you to find out what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attributes` option with `sequelize.json`

```
const payload = await sequelize.<modelname>.findAll({
               attributes: ['id',
                           [sequelize.json('name.last'), 'last']]
    });
```

It means like:
`select id, name->>'last' as last from ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by `sequelize.literal`

```
const users = await sequalize.<model>.findAll({
  where: sequelize.literal("name->>'last' = 'bar'")
});
```

it will produce query like

```
SELECT * FROM "<model>" WHERE name->>'last' = 'bar';
```

If you want to add columns like

```
SELECT id, name->>'last' FROM ...
```

you can define it by `attributes`

```
const users = await sequelize.<model>.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
    [sequelize.literal("name->>'last'"), 'last']
  ]
});
```